# Expanding textarea onload doesn't expand HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've managed to get my textarea field to grow and shrink on input. However if you already have content in here that exceeds more than one line it doesn't automatically load as multiple lines.

Any ideas? Or hints? Thanks

```
$(document)
.on('focus.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', 'change.autoExpand',  function(){

    var savedValue = this.value;
    this.value = '';
    this.baseScrollHeight = this.scrollHeight;
    this.value = savedValue;
})
.on('input.autoExpand', 'textarea.autoExpand', 'change.autoExpand',  function(){
    var minRows = this.getAttribute('data-min-rows')|0, rows;
    this.rows = minRows;
    rows = Math.ceil((this.scrollHeight - this.baseScrollHeight) / 16);
    this.rows = minRows + rows;
});
```

Comment: I've been playing with this for a while and don't seem to be able to reproduce. Could you give at least a snippet of your HTML and whatever else may be necessary to make it so the textarea 'already [has] content ... more than one line ... doesn't ... load as multiple lines'?

Comment: <div class="double-column" >
 <TEXTAREA CLASS="autoExpand valueEditable" ID="Req" NAME="Req" TITLE="Reason for Request" WRAP="soft" ROWS="1" COLS="100" ONFOCUS=""  onload-"" ONCHANGE="markDirty();" placeholder="">  </TEXTAREA>
 
      <span class="highlight"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
 <label>Reason Requested</label>
      </div>

Do you need the CSS?